# jQuery: to detach or not to detach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, detach

I read that [it is good to detach elements before working with them](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/detach-elements-before-work-with-them/) but I was wondering

- when is it worth it? when not?

  for example, I have an HTML table with rows, I update one row by changing the values of the cells (5 cells or so) and adding a class to the row. Is it worth detaching the row off the table and then attaching it back?
- how to deal with the fact that the element "disappear" for a while?

  if I understood well, detaching the element removes it from the DOM, and therefore it kind of "disappears" (I mean visually). Is there a way to prevent it? ( Maybe something like creating copy of the element, working on it and then swapping the 2? )
- if I want to reattach the element where it was before, is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: It doesn't worth it (and even worst if you just detach it to reappend them on the fly). Use instead cached reference of elements